# How to create multiple directories in Ranger?

Tags: directory, mkdir, ranger

As in the equivalent of `mkdir dir1 dir2` when running in bash. This creates two separate directories, `dir1` and `dir2`.

If you run `:mkdir dir1 dir2` in ranger, it simply creates a directory called `'dir1 dir2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ranger doesn't use `mkdir` flags. (I tried to pass it, and it doesn't work.)

But ranger provides the use of alias.

```
alias [newcommand] [oldcommand]
         Copies the oldcommand as newcommand.
```

So when you launch ranger you can set one to execute `mkdir` with the flags you need.

```
:alias mkdir shell mkdir -p
```

And then you can do:

```
:mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

Stemming off of tntx's answer above, adding

```
alias mkdir shell mkdir -p
```

to my `rc.conf` works exactly as expected. This is preferred as it will automatically be loaded into `ranger` on startup